# SQL Server query with subquery not filter correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I am trying to get the higher price of the most expensive product (laptop, pc or printer). So I tried this query:

```
select price 
from 
    (select price, model 
     from printer 

     union

     select price, model 
     from pc

     union

     select price, model 
     from laptop) t
where 
    price >= All (select t.price);
```

but this returns me all prices. If I change last line to be:

```
where price > All (select t.price);
```

I don't get any results.

So why is that? I tried last line to be: `where price >= All (select price from t);`, but it's not working ( it says that t is invalid object - why???).

Can someone show me how to fix this query?

I accept recommendations for better ways of doing this, but I will appreciate If someone can fix this query and makes it works.

Thanks for your attention

P.S. I assume that `(select t.price);` do not generate the whole list of prices, but how can I generate it in this subquery when `(select price from t)` is not valid request?

Comment: To answer your first question: `select t.price` is a _correlated subquery_. You have effectively written `where t.price >= t.price` which is `true` for all non-null prices. Changing the clause to `where t.price > t.price` results in zero rows because no price is greater than itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `MAX` function in your query

```
select MAX(price) as maximum_price
from (select price, model from printer 
    union
    select price, model from pc
    union
    select price, model from laptop) t
```

For fixing your query in your way try below

```
select price 
from (select price, model from printer 
    union
    select price, model from pc
    union
    select price, model from laptop) t
where t.price>= ALL( 
                   select price from printer 
                        union
                    select price from pc
                         union
                    select price from laptop

                   )
```

Same using CTE approach:

```
with t (price,model) as
(
select price, model from printer 
    union
    select price, model from pc
    union
    select price, model from laptop)


select price 
from t 
where t.price>= ALL(

                   select price from t

                   )
```

Comment: And why in your last example ` select price from t` works ? `t` is like an existing table (in perspective of the query).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method without `where`:

```
select top 1 t.* 
from (select price, model from printer 
      union all
      select price, model from pc
      union all
      select price, model from laptop
     ) t
order by price desc;
```

This allows you to get the model as well as the price.